# Virgin-acl nodejs

Tags: node.js

Preciso criar permissões de acesso em minha página, porém não faço ideia por onde começar.
Instalei o `virgin-acl`.

Tenho por exemplo a pagina abaixo e quero que um usuarioexemplo apenas visualize:

```
app.get('/usuarios/novo', isLoggedIn, usuario.novo);
```

Gostaria que ao acessar, fosse verificado o ID do usuário e se o mesmo tem permissão para visualizar esta pagina.

O correto seria usar, como o exemplo a seguir:

```
acl.isAllowed('usuarioexemplo', 'usuarios', 'view', function(err, res){  
    if(res){  
        console.log("User joed is allowed to view blogs")  
    }  
}
```

Mas onde crio estas regras? No controller? No router? No app?

Comment: Podes juntar o link para esse `virgin-acl`?